# Converting projected coordinates to lat/lon using Python

Tags: python, coordinate-system, convert, pyproj

[This site](http://jeffco.us/ArcGIS/rest/services/sch/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?SingleKey=000090&Single%20Line%20Input=&outFields=&outSR=&f=html) returns

```
Point:
X: -11705274.6374
Y: 4826473.6922
```

when you search with the first key value of 000090, as an example. I assume that this is a spatial reference.

I am looking for instructions, or examples, of how to convert this to latitude and longitude using Python.

Comment: That site returns: "Access to the application you were trying to use has been blocked in accordance with County policy. Please contact your organization's Service Desk if you believe this is in error."

Answer (score 159, accepted):

The simplest way to transform coordinates in Python is **[pyproj](http://code.google.com/p/pyproj/)**, i.e. the *Python interface to PROJ.4 library*.

### Recommended solution since pyproj 2

pyproj 2.0.0 was released March 8th 2019.

```
from pyproj import Transformer
transformer = Transformer.from_crs("EPSG:3857", "EPSG:4326")
transformer.transform(-11705274.6374,4826473.6922)
```

Source: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#upgrading-to-pyproj-2-from-pyproj-1

### Deprecated solution

The solution originally posted in this answer is shown below. This method has been discouraged since version 2.0, and some parts now result in deprecation warnings.

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform

# inProj = Proj(init='epsg:3857') # deprecated since 2.4
# outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326') # deprecated since 2.4
inProj = Proj('epsg:3857')  
outProj = Proj('epsg:4326') 
x1,y1 = -11705274.6374,4826473.6922
x2,y2 = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1) # deprecated some time later than 2.4
print x2,y2 # `-105.150271116 39.7278572773`
```

Comment: pyproj 2.4 gives a FutureWarning about deprecated Proj() initialization with the `init=` syntax. The updated syntax is identical but without the `init=`. Like this: 

`inProj = Proj('epsg:3857')` and 
`outProj = Proj('epsg:4326')`

Comment: I removed the `'init='` based on the edit, but my output of `transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)` gave me `(latitude, longitude)` instead of `(longitude, latitude)`. Anybody knows why ?

Comment: @gdelab See https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/issues/538#issuecomment-585734088

Comment: This might be helpful to reference: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#upgrading-to-pyproj-2-from-pyproj-1

Comment: This will also be good to reference: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#axis-order-changes-in-proj-6

Comment: Now `transform` is also deprecated: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#upgrading-to-pyproj-2-from-pyproj-1

Comment: As zabob said, now, recommended usage is: `transformer = Transformer.from_crs("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857")` `x2, y2 = transformer.transform(x1, y1)`

Answer (score 41):

By default the site you linked to uses the Spatial Reference System EPSG 3857 (WGS84 Web Mercator). I found this information [here](http://jeffco.us/ArcGIS/rest/services/sch/GeocodeServer).

You can either specify another Spatial Reference System by entering the desired EPSG into the form under `Spatial Reference` or you can convert the returned coordinates with Python.

For instance you can use the [GDAL Python bindings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/) to convert this point from the projected coordinate system (EPSG 3857) to a geographic coordinate system (EPSG 4326).

```
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo import osr  


pointX = -11705274.6374 
pointY = 4826473.6922

# Spatial Reference System
inputEPSG = 3857
outputEPSG = 4326

# create a geometry from coordinates
point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
point.AddPoint(pointX, pointY)

# create coordinate transformation
inSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
inSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(inputEPSG)

outSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
outSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(outputEPSG)

coordTransform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(inSpatialRef, outSpatialRef)

# transform point
point.Transform(coordTransform)

# print point in EPSG 4326
print point.GetX(), point.GetY()
```

This returns for your point the coordinates of `-105.150271116 39.7278572773`.

Comment: @Thomas it is returning 39.7278572773 -105.150271116, why is it flipping coordinates?

Comment: The only comment is about the `print`, just add brackets to print without errors (for python 3 +)

Comment: `point.AddPoint(pointY, pointX)`  is LAT LONG

Answer (score 20):

When using pyproj, note the differences from various releases in how it is used to transform data. Here are a few examples using new/old capabilities based on the question:

## Using pyproj >= 2.2.0

```
import pyproj
print(pyproj.__version__)  # 2.4.1
print(pyproj.proj_version_str) # 6.2.1

proj = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(3857, 4326, always_xy=True)

x1, y1 = (-11705274.6374, 4826473.6922)
x2, y2 = proj.transform(x1, y1)
print((x2, y2))  # (-105.15027111593008, 39.72785727727918)
```

## Using pyproj <= 1.9.6

```
import pyproj
print(pyproj.__version__)  # 1.9.6
print(pyproj.proj_version_str) # 4.9.3

inProj = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:3857')
outProj = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326')

x1, y1 = (-11705274.6374, 4826473.6922)
x2, y2 = pyproj.transform(inProj, outProj, x1, y1)
print((x2, y2))  # (-105.15027111593008, 39.72785727727918)
```

---

There are a few considerations with the different versions of PROJ/pyproj:

- `transform` for older versions *always* return the same axis order of "x, y" or "longitude, latitude", whereas PROJ 6+ is the order as defined by EPSG, unless an option like `always_xy=True` is specified
- `Proj` is limited to converting between geographic and projection coordinates within one datum, whereas the newer `Transformer` takes into account datum shifts, and is recommended for newer pyproj use

Answer (score 13):

afalciano has the right answer but wanted to include a variant usage of pyproj.

It *does* require you know the proj4 string and is a tiny bit faster.

```python
import pyproj
p = pyproj.Proj("+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")
lon, lat = p(x, y, inverse=True)
print lat, lon
```

Comment: You don't need the proj4 string, substitute the second line for `p = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:3857')` and the result is the same.

Comment: The result is the same but last I checked this was a tiny bit faster.

Comment: Even though it was not the intention of this answer, it is particularly useful when you have a totally custom projection, which is not listed in the EPSG-repository.

Answer (score 8):

The output is not a [spatial/coordinate reference system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system), it's a pair of coordinates.  You need to know what the spatial reference is to reproject the coordinates.

However, that's not required in this case.  Just pass an appropriate output spatial reference to the service and it will return the coordinates in Lon/Lat.

Here is the [page](http://jeffco.us/ArcGIS/rest/services/sch/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?SingleKey=000090&Single%20Line%20Input=&outFields=&outSR=4326&f=html) with output coordinates in Lon/Lat format using the WGS-84 geographic spatial reference system ([EPSG 4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/)).

Answer (score 7):

Tried the code suggested by Marcel Wilson and it is faster:

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform
import time
import pyproj


# Test 1 - 0.0006158 s
start=time.time()
inProj = Proj(init='epsg:3857')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')
x1,y1 = -11705274.6374,4826473.6922
x2,y2 = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)
end=time.time()
print(y2,x2)
print('%.7f' % (end-start))

# Test 2 - 0.0000517 s --- factor 11,9
start=time.time()
x,y = -11705274.6374,4826473.6922
p = pyproj.Proj("+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")
lon, lat = p(x, y, inverse=True)
end=time.time()
print(lat, lon)
print('%.7f' % (end-start))
-----------------

39.72785727727918 -105.15027111593008
0.0006158
39.72785727727918 -105.15027111593008
0.0000517
```

Answer (score 5):

I found this post when looking for ways of doing this within QGIS. As described [here](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/crs.html), the method used looks like so:

```
def convertProjection(self,x,y,from_crs,to_crs):
    crsSrc = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(from_crs)
    crsDest = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(to_crs)
    xform = QgsCoordinateTransform(crsSrc, crsDest)
    pt = xform.transform(QgsPoint(x,y))
    return pt.x, pt.y

# Remove the "EPSG:" part
from_crs = 3857
to_crs = 4326
x = -11705274.6374    
y = 4826473.6922
lon, lat = self.convertProjection(x,y,from_crs, to_crs)
```

Comment: Note, there's a breaking API change in QGIS 3, so if using `v3.x` you'll need to use `xform = QgsCoordinateTransform(crsSrc, crsDest, QgsProject.instance()) `

Comment: Also see _PyQgis Cookbook >> Projection Support >> CRS Transformation_, https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/crs.html#crs-transformation, and how to transform an entire layer here on Stack: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109235/how-to-make-crs-transformation-of-a-qgsvectorlayer

Answer (score 5):

Please note that the `transform` function of `pyproj` accepts also `arrays`, which is quite useful when it comes to dataframes

```
import pandas as pd
from pyproj import Proj, transform

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [-11705274.6374]*100, 
                   'y': [4826473.6922]*100})
inProj, outProj = Proj(init='epsg:3857'), Proj(init='epsg:4326')
df['x2'], df['y2'] = transform(inProj, outProj, df['x'].tolist(), df['y'].tolist())
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a shorter version of [ustroetz's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/78850/109091) since the `ogr.wkbPoint` geometry is not required for a point.

```
from osgeo import osr  


pointX = -11705274.6374 
pointY = 4826473.6922
pointZ = 0.0

# Spatial Reference System
inputEPSG = 3857
outputEPSG = 4326

# create coordinate transformation
inSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
inSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(inputEPSG)

outSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
outSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(outputEPSG)

coordTransform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(inSpatialRef, outSpatialRef)

# transform point, height z is optional
x, y, z = coordTransform.TransformPoint(pointX, pointY, pointZ)

# print point in EPSG 4326
print(x, y)
```

Answer (score -2):

convert esri extent bbox to lat long

1. use esri javascipt api module ( **client side projection, fast, no need ajax, no need internet, projection done in your browser, extremely fast**)

   first include css, js

> link(rel='stylesheet',href='https://js.arcgis.com/4.17/esri/themes/light/main.css')
> script(src='https://js.arcgis.com/4.17/')

This is my working example:
[image]

2. **proj4js** ( need ajax, internet to read projection string from website, due to website does not allow jsonp, not allow cors, you have to setup your own proxy to bypass CORS problem, not easy for normal user )

But if you already known from what to what, then you can just copy past projection string, no internet needed, all projectin done in your browser.

If you don't know project from what to what, projection wkid is dynamic generated in the runtime, then like I said previously, you must need ajax, need internet to read projection string from website on the fly, in the run time. It is not easy, because you have to bypass CORS problem.

Here is my working example:
[image]

3. use Arcgis.com hosted web service ( need internet, very slow, not reliable, if ESRI server is crowded, you might get it very slow. Every ajax request can only conver one pair of lat lng)
   [image]

[image]

Here is how to project on website
[image]

you can get xmin, ymin from here
[image]

Comment: Downvoted because the question is tagged `python` and this answer uses JavaScript exclusively. Also the screenshots... please don't do this on Stack Exchange.