# Converting decimal latitude/longitude bounding box to SRID 26910

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, convert

I have a bounding box specified in decimal latitude/longitude, and need to convert this into a bounding box in the [SRID 26910](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::26910) coordinate system.

I've never had to work with different GIS coordinate systems before, and haven't been able to find anything about SRID 26910 through Googling around.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction on how to go about this?

The conversion would be done in Python code.

My end goal is to provide a correct bbox parameter to the http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/rest/export.html API, when imageSR and bboxSR are provided as SRID 26910.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SRID and EPSG codes correspond to each other, so you better look for the EPSG code which is easier to find on the Web. In your case it is [NAD83 / UTM zone 10N](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/nad83-utm-zone-10n/)

With your box stored in a feature class, you can use [arcpy.project_management()](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000007m000000)

your coordinate system would be :

```
out_coordinate_system = arcpy.SpatialReference("NAD 1983 UTM Zone 10N")
```

Last but not least, you need to check what datum is used for your Long/lat coordinate system. If it is not NAD 1983, you need to add a transformation (e.g. NAD_1983_to_WGS_1984_1 )

Comment: Thanks, once I started searching for "EPSG 26910", I found what I needed. The following answer was helpful for the actual conversion: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78838/how-to-convert-projected-coordinates-to-lat-lon-using-python