# Getting origin as long, lat in GDAL without knowing EPSG

Tags: gdal, latitude-longitude

My goal is to get the long, lat coordinates for the origin of a particular geotif.

gdalinfo outputs:
`Upper Left (-2764486.928, 3232110.510) (130d 7'22.42"W, 49d56'48.81"N)`
But I don't understand the meaning of `(-2764486.928, 3232110.510)` - for instance what units are being represented here?

What I want is something like:
`Upper Left  (-125.0208333,  49.9375000) (125d 1'15.00"W, 49d56'15.00"N)` 
which `gdalinfo` yields on a different geotiff file that I have.

I'm actually using `ds.GetGeoTransform()` in python to get this same information `gdalinfo` outputs and am looking for a solution in python to convert `(-2764486.928, 3232110.510)` into a long, lat. I tried fmark's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922532/obtain-latitude-and-longitude-from-a-geotiff-file), but it didn't convert `(-2764486.928, 3232110.510)` into a long,lat.

Here is the entire gdalinfo output

> Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
>   Files: mask.tif
>   Size is 2145, 1377
>   Coordinate System is:
>   PROJCS["unnamed",
>       GEOGCS["Coordinate System imported from GRIB file",
>           DATUM["unknown",
>               SPHEROID["Sphere",6371229,0]],
>           PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
>           UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
>       PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],
>       PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",25],
>       PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",25],
>       PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",25],
>       PARAMETER["central_meridian",265],
>       PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
>       PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
>       UNIT["metre",1,
>           AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
>   Origin = (-2764486.928100540300000,3232110.510093217700000)
>   Pixel Size = (2539.703000000000000,-2539.703000000000000)
>   Metadata:
>     AREA_OR_POINT=Area
>   Image Structure Metadata:
>     INTERLEAVE=BAND
>   Corner Coordinates:
>   Upper Left  (-2764486.928, 3232110.510) (130d 7'22.42"W, 49d56'48.81"N)
>   Lower Left  (-2764486.928, -265060.521) (121d33'48.72"W, 20d10'43.04"N)
>   Upper Right ( 2683176.007, 3232110.510) ( 60d51'59.22"W, 50d 6'46.25"N)
>   Lower Right ( 2683176.007, -265060.521) ( 69d11'55.57"W, 20d19' 6.55"N)
>   Center      (  -40655.461, 1483524.995) ( 95d27' 9.15"W, 38d13' 5.62"N)
>   Band 1 Block=2145x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray

Here's what I tried in python:

```
geo_transform = ds.GetGeoTransform()
old_cs= osr.SpatialReference()
old_cs.ImportFromWkt(ds.GetProjectionRef())
wkt = """
    GEOGCS["NAD83",
    DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
        SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010002,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
        TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]]"""
new_cs = osr.SpatialReference()
new_cs.ImportFromWkt(wkt)
transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(old_cs,new_cs)
width = ds.RasterXSize
height = ds.RasterYSize
gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()

#get the coordinates in lat long
latlong = transform.TransformPoint(gt[0], gt[3])
```

The output is `latlong = (-2764486.928, 3232110.510, 0.0)`

Using BradHards's [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78838/how-to-convert-projected-coordinates-to-lat-lon-using-python), I've got the code pasted below and believe I just need to figure out the source geotiffs EPSG. `gdalinfo` says it's 9001, but when I try using that the code blows up with

```
TypeError: in method 'Geometry_Transform', argument 2 of type 'OSRCoordinateTransformationShadow *'
```

The geotiff originated as a GRIB file from [nomads](http://nomads.ncdc.noaa.gov/data/ndgd/201405/20140519/LTIA98_KWBR_201405190400)

```
ds = gdal.Open("mygeotiff")
gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()
long_lat = get_point_as_long_lat(gt[0], gt[3], ???what_epsg???)


def get_point_as_long_lat(coord_x, coord_y, input_epsg):
  # Spatial Reference System
  output_epsg = 4326

  # create a geometry from coordinates
  point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
  point.AddPoint(coord_x, coord_y)

  # create coordinate transformation
  in_spatial_ref = osr.SpatialReference()
  in_spatial_ref.ImportFromEPSG(input_epsg)

  out_spatial_ref = osr.SpatialReference()
  out_spatial_ref.ImportFromEPSG(output_epsg)

  coord_transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(in_spatial_ref, out_spatial_ref)

  # transform point
  point.Transform(coord_transform)

  # return point in EPSG 4326
  return point.GetX(), point.GetY()
```

Comment: Please list what you did in python, and what you got.

Comment: @mdsummer python code and result has been added.

Comment: new_cs should be the string for long-lat, here it's the same as the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the pointers all. I now understand that even though my source geotif has no EPSG I can get its projection from wkt and view it as proj.4:

```
ds = gdal.Open("mygeotiff")
in_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
in_srs.ImportFromWkt(ds.GetProjection())
print(in_srs.ExportToProj4()) : '+proj=lcc +lat_1=25 +lat_2=25 +lat_0=25 +lon_0=265 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371229 +b=6371229 +units=m +no_defs '
```

The below code translates coordinates to long, lat in 4326 correctly without having a source EPSG:

```
# translates coord_x, coord_y from in_spatial_ref to coords in output_epsg
def get_point_as_long_lat(coord_x, coord_y, in_spatial_ref, output_epsg):
  # target Spatial Reference System
  out_spatial_ref = osr.SpatialReference()
  out_spatial_ref.ImportFromEPSG(output_epsg)

  coord_transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(in_spatial_ref, out_spatial_ref)

  # create a geometry from coordinates
  point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
  point.AddPoint(coord_x, coord_y)

  # transform point
  point.Transform(coord_transform)

  # return point in EPSG 4326
  return point.GetX(), point.GetY()


ds = gdal.Open("mygeotiff")
gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()

in_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
in_srs.ImportFromWkt(ds.GetProjection())

origin_long_lat = get_point_as_long_lat(geo_transform[0], geo_transform[3], in_srs, 4326)
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27572190/) reveals that GDAL may fail to read information, so importing WKT from another dataset as you did or simply hardcoding WKT or PROJ.4 parameters solves the error.

Answer (score 4):

The coordinates are in the spatial reference system described in the file.

So `-2764486.928, 3232110.510` is referenced to something (that gdal doesn't have a name for). The something is:

```
PROJCS["unnamed",
GEOGCS["Coordinate System imported from GRIB file",
DATUM["unknown",
SPHEROID["Sphere",6371229,0]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],
PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",25],
PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",25],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",25],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",265],
PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["metre",1,
AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
```

`gdalinfo` does show it in something more familiar - the part following: `(130d 7'22.42"W, 49d56'48.81"N)`. You should be able to get that with python too. You haven't posted all of the code (e.g. how did you open the dataset), but there are plenty of examples, including [How to convert projected coordinates to lat/lon using Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78838/how-to-convert-projected-coordinates-to-lat-lon-using-python)

Comment: I think the link you pointed me to is probably the solution, but I don't know what my source EPSG is. GDAL info says AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"] but when I try going from 9001 to 4326 I get the error: TypeError: in method 'Geometry_Transform', argument 2 of type 'OSRCoordinateTransformationShadow *'

Comment: 9001 is the EPSG code for a metre (i.e. that is part of the `UNIT`), not a projected coordinate system.

Comment: Your source CRS does not have an EPSG number (and does not have to, because you can build projections with almost any parameter set you want).