# Create a grid over shapefile then save each section into GeoTIFF

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, vector, geotiff-tiff

I have a massive shapefile with 200,000+ building polygons. I've loaded these up in ArcGIS. I need to convert this into a usable raster (GeoTIFF) that can then be tiled using MapTiler.

My current process is as follows:

1. Click on the Full Extent icon in order to have all the polygons in
   my current view. The scale is at 1:261,289.
2. Export this as raster using File > Export Map > TIFF > Write GeoTIFF tags (in Format tab). Set the dpi to 500.
3. When zoomed all the way into this GeoTIFF image, the result looks
   too pixelated. You can barely tell they are polygons.

[image: A small section of the file]

I need to the scale to be at 1:26,261 (or 1:25,000 for simplicity) in order to get decent looking polygons.

**How can I create a grid over this vector file with 200,000+ polygons and then save each section into a GeoTIFF file at 1:26,261 scale?**

I also tried this in QGIS. Similar issues, though somewhat better results in ArcGIS.

Comment: Check my answer here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190966/export-arcgis-tiles-data-to-any-image-format

Comment: @FelixIP The code ran but am not seeing the results for some reason.

Comment: No files, or they blank? Try with 1 page manually. If it works read answer again

Comment: @FelixIP No files. I have specified my output folder as `env.workspace = 'C:\Temp'`

Comment: @FelixIP I didn't quite understand this part of your comment: `What field are you using to store it in DDP index layer?`. Is this field referenced in the code?

Comment: It is about field for page name. Must be text. Order of pages has to be =order of rows in the table

Comment: outFolder=r'c:\temp' leave the rest as is in original code

Comment: @FelixIP Ah, I missed the "r" before specifying the directory. It works now. Is there a way I can specify a resolution for the PNGs? Is it just adding `resolution=300` as one of the parameters in `ExportToPNG`?

Comment: Set  dpi=300 at the top of the script.

Comment: @FelixIP Hmm, the default in your code was set to 1200, but the image size is 386px by 386px. That doesn't seem right? Shouldn't the dimensions be much larger?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39197/discussion-between-felixip-and-mapr).

Answer (score 1):

You could use Create Fishnet of 200,000+ polygons to create a grid over your vector file, then use this as the index layer for Data Driven Pages.

You can then export those 200,000+ pages to TIFF using the flag to create a world file for each.

I have not tested the above but I would expect it to work with no more than minor tweaking to the procedure as described.