# Convert image from WMS service to Shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.1, wms

I have a layer on ArcGIS that I want to convert to a Shapefile. This layer was created from a WMS server, so it's an image. The link to this shape is this one https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=64ca041031d0429e862433f6cc5d0cd1.

Is there a way to do that?

I've got this layer from a WMS server.

Comment: Use https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190966/export-arcgis-tiles-data-to-any-image-format/191623#191623 to grab high resolution images from server. Mosaic to single image. There are very few distinct colors, so you can use image classification to get something very close to original.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is No. There is no  way to convert WMS services to shapefile format.But with WFS services, you can extract the geometries If you have permission to access the geometries of layers.
[WFS services in ArcGIS](ftp://gisftp.hicentral.com/ArcGIS/ArcGIS/Manager/Help/wfs_service.htm)

see an example: [How to download a shapefile from GeoServer](https://wiki.state.ma.us/display/massgis/GeoServer+-+WFS+-+Extract+-+Shapefile+Format)