# Using a base layer from ESRI and converting to a regular layer and "cropping it" also using it for arcScene

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, 3d-analyst, arcscene, arcgis-online-basemaps

How do I modify a baselayer from Esri?

I found a great one for my region (much better resolution than the one I was given) but it is way too big and I want to cut out the ocean part of the raster so I just have the city map.  It is sort of like what you would see with google earth. I would also like to use it for my ArcScene to make nice 3D images but it does not seem that is an option.

I am a bit of a beginner.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190966/export-arcgis-tiles-data-to-any-image-format/191623#191623

Comment: FelizlP I don't understand what you are saying.  I went to that.  But the problem is that I want to START with the basemap that I get from ArcGIS.  I am not trying to make a basemap.  I am trying to take their basemap and crop it and make it into a raster that I can modify based on what I need.  Can you help with that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To clip data from an Esri Basemap have a polygon that outlines the area you want to clip. Go to View and then Data Frame Properties. Within the Data Frame tab under ‘Clip Options’ select ‘Clip to Shape’ and on the box to the right select specify shape.  Set your ‘Outline of Features’ layer to your polygon you want to clip and then hit OK.

The below example shows an Esri Imagery Basemap in which I want to only show imagery for the area of Philadelphia.

[image]

[image]