# Cropping main map layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, clip

How do I crop the main layer in which the base map and other features are placed on?

I want to work on a select portion of the map as opposed to the entire layout.
I've used the clip function but this is used for features only.

Comment: See if this helps https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190966/export-arcgis-tiles-data-to-any-image-format/191623#191623