# Converting polyline coordinates to lat/lon for use in google maps

Tags: python, coordinate-system, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I am given an ArcGIS polyline (or polypoint) from a WFS service (e.g. 1693669.5143, 5672605.5392), and am looking for a function (python, java, whatever) to convert it to a lat/lon so I can use it in Google Maps. I obviously have the projection as well.

I've googled this extensively but most of the results return ArcGIS's solution http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-xy-coordinates.htm - i.e. tool-specific

Is there an online tool or converter to do this, or (ideally) a function or library that I can use directly from code?

Comment: Ask the WFS to return already projected coordinates, or use [pyproj](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78838/how-to-convert-projected-coordinates-to-lat-lon-using-python), or [arcpy.Geometry.ProjectAs](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/geometry.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `srsName=` string to get the polyline from the WFS in lat/lon coordinates from the start.

Alternatively, provided that you've read the coordinate strings into Python as arrays `x` and `y`, you can do

```
import pyproj
prj = pyproj.Proj(PROJ4_STRING)
lon, lat = prj(x, y, inverse=True)
```

where PROJ4_STRING is the libproj SRS string for the original projection.

Comment: Can you post an example on how to use `srsName`?