# Converting state plane coordinates to latitude/longitude

Tags: python, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, epsg, pyproj

I'm trying to convert pairs of x,y coordinates to latitude/longitude using python.  The projection is "NAD_1983_HARN_StatePlane_Oregon_North_FIPS_3601_Feet_Intl" and a sample x,y pair is 7625659, 714714.  So far, I have found [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78838/how-to-convert-projected-coordinates-to-lat-lon-using-python) question and have tried using the code in the first solution:

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform

inProj = Proj(init='epsg:????')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:????')
x1,y1 = 7625659,714714
x2,y2 = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)
print x2,y2
```

However, I'm having trouble finding an epsg code for the location.  I came across [this](http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7972/) but I can't seem to find the epsg code for that area.  All I can see is the sr-org code.  Also, it seems strange that the location on the map is not in Oregon.  I was able to convert it (the output looked reasonable) using the tool at http://beta.ngs.noaa.gov/gtkweb/ using datum=NAD83, projection for conversion=SPC, Norting=714714, Easting=7625659, Units=International feet and SPC Zone=OR N-3601.  How should I convert this projection to latitude and longitude?

Edit:
I tried using the tool at http://prj2epsg.org/search which gave me 2913 (I also tried 3646 per BradHards suggestion, it came up the same) for inProj and 4326 (BradHards) for outProj, but it's giving me a location (-62.0472510133 32.7243167795) which is in the middle of the ocean, not in Portland.  The lat/lon from http://beta.ngs.noaa.gov/gtkweb/ is (45.605018016, -122.752592697) which is in Portland (Sorry, I can't comment on the site...).

Comment: Have a look at this, http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4152/

Comment: The outProj is probably meant to be `epsg:4326` if you want WGS-84 longitude / latitude. It might be something else if you want a different ellipsoid. Perhaps `epsg:3646` for the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to add `preserve_units = True` and the epsg codes provided by BradHards.

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform

inProj = Proj(init='epsg:3646', preserve_units = True)
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')
x1,y1 = 7625659,714714
x2,y2 = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)
print x2,y2
```

This returns lat/lon `(-122.752652268, 45.6050168495)`.  Strangely enough http://beta.ngs.noaa.gov/gtkweb/ gives me lon/lat `(-122.752592697, 45.605018016)` which is a couple of feet over.  I'm going to assume that's a round off error somewhere and it shouldn't make too much of a difference.

Comment: I suggest you [merge your accounts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) rather than posting an answer as another user.