# Convert ArcGIS SVY21 X,Y coordinates to GPS lat long python only

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, coordinate-system

I have X,Y coordinates of points in the following CSV Form:

```
     X              Y
  28052.96459,44641.90785
```

These follow the SVY21 Projection system, and the details of the coordinates are as follows:

```
Projected Coordinate System:    SVY21
Projection: Transverse_Mercator
False_Easting:  28001.64200000
False_Northing: 38744.57200000
Central_Meridian:   103.83333333
Scale_Factor:   1.00000000
Latitude_Of_Origin: 1.36666667
Linear Unit:    Meter
```

However, I'm using this for google maps, and require the GPS lat long instead. I do not have access to ArcGIS.

Is there a way I can convert the points to lat / long? Preferably using python and its packages.

I have tried the following library: https://github.com/cgcai/SVY21 and it gives very inaccurate results.

Comment: Not clear what are you asking. Is input data text, shapefile or geodatabase? What output format do you need (clear text or kmz etc.)? Similar question (possible duplicate): http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78838/how-to-convert-projected-coordinates-to-lat-lon-using-python

Comment: Text csv. I just need to convert them to latitude,longitude.

Comment: What does it mean arcgis x,y? You mixing things... arcgis is not a projection or coordinate system.

Comment: Hey @Balazs, Yes I know. the projection system is mentioned in my post (SVY21). I thought that was clear enough, but ill edit it. Also, ive figured out how, but I cant answer it now because its on hold. ugh.