# Converting from custom projection northing/easting coords to lat/long in decimal degrees

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, coordinates, reprojection-mathematics

I've got a custom projection file that's applied to all data (per request of a client), and another team is requesting ids/coordinate pairs for assets. I tried ripping out X/Y off the point data, but I noticed the coordinates make no sense - they are not standard UTM northings/eastings.

**For instance**:

A point with real-world coords of 43.814794N, -76.02576907720452 has these coordinates in the weird custom projection: X: -534643.85116969, Y: 303444.080342568

The GCS is WGS84, but none of the online converters or formulas I can find work, and nobody has any clear instructions on how to create a formula. What I need is to write a Python function that will convert the eastings/northings to decimal degrees. Anyone have knowledge of how to develop such a formula?

**Here's the info on the projection:**

```
  False_Easting       |  0.000000000000000000

  False_Northing      |  0.000000000000000000

  Central_Meridian    |  -74.000000000000000000

  Standard_Parallel_1 | 42.000000000000000000

  Standard_Parallel_2 | 44.000000000000000000

  Latitude_Of_Origin  | 43.000000000000000000
```

**And here's the info on the GCS (WGS84):**

```
Name: GCS_WGS_1984

Angular Unit: Degree (0.0174532925199433)

Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0.0)

Datum: D_WGS_1984

  Spheroid: WGS_1984

    Semimajor Axis: 6378137.0

    Semiminor Axis: 6356752.314245179

    Inverse Flattening: 298.257223563
```

Comment: You tagged arcpy which works with ArcGIS and you have an Esri-style coordinate system definition. Do you have access to ArcGIS?

Comment: Your coordinate reference system information is missing the projection algorithm. The parameters are for a conic projection--is it Lambert conformal conic or Albers equal area conic?

Comment: @mkennedy yes, but I'm trying to avoid GP tools. I'd rather do calculations on X/Y extracted from Point objects on the fly in my loop that collects coordinate data. And neither - it is a custom conic projection. The client called it "Equidistant Conic." I posted everything available in the Proj file properties in ArcCatalog.

Comment: Then you'll need to implement the equations on p114 of John P. Snyder's [Map Projections: A Working Manual](https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/pp1395) or try using pyproj maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you decide to use pyproj (an excellent recommendation from @mkennedy), here is a projection string that may work:

```
+proj=eqdc +lat_0=43 +lat_1=42 +lat_2=44 +lon_0=-74 +datum=WGS84 +units=us-ft +no_defs
```

Using this [online converter](https://mygeodata.cloud/cs2cs/), it gives a result close to your example.

Input: `+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs`

Output: `+proj=eqdc +lat_0=43 +lat_1=42 +lat_2=44 +lon_0=-74 +datum=WGS84 +units=us-ft +no_defs`

> 43.814794, -76.02576907720452
>
> Switch X <--> Y

Gives:

> -534643.334276 ; 303440.613642

If you search this site, there are many excellent answers with examples of using pyproj; [here is just one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/253686/43).

Comment: Thank you @Richard Morgan! I haven't had a chance to apply this yet (I work a different project Thurs-Fri), but I'll give it a shot Monday when I'm back at the client site!