# Converting QGIS X,Y info to lat, long using Python

Tags: qgis, python, coordinate-system, pyproj

I am trying to convert QGIS x,y points into the lat, long coordinates. I have (335687.7471962841, 4487822.535352517) supposedly point to somewhere in the Chicago metropolitan area. I tried the accepted answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78838/converting-projected-coordinates-to-lat-lon-using-python) (without inits) and got (37.34869549513416 3.0155343399807206) which is somewhere in the Mediterranean Sea. Where am I doing wrong?

Here is what I have done:

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform

inProj = Proj('epsg:3857')
outProj = Proj('epsg:4326')
x1,y1 = 335687.7471962841,4487822.535352517
x2,y2 = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)
print (x2,y2)

Output:
37.34869549513416 3.0155343399807206
```

Comment: You could try reprojecting your points layer into EPSG:4326.

Comment: I think that is what I have already done with the above code, right?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with any terms of this field.

Comment: Yes, that's what that code does. Are you sure your original coordinates are in 3857?

Comment: I have no idea about it. Only thing I know they came from QGIS.

Comment: The code is correct: your input coordinates are not in Chicago, but in the Mediterranean.

Comment: @ThibauldCroonenborghs True, but only if his original CRS is EPSG:3857. I'm guessing he's assuming the wrong CRS for his coordinates.

Comment: @user8028576 In QGIS, start a new project. Drag your points file into that project (or add them). Double-click on them in the "Layers" panel. Click on the "information" tab. Find "CRS" and report what you see there.

Comment: The coordinates you have probably are UTM coordinates. I guess NAD83 / UTM Zone 16N (EPSG:26916)

Comment: Tried EPSG 26716 & 26916 but didn't answer. The coordinates are quite far from Chicago (around 200km), more or less in Bloomington

Comment: Bloomington is the correct location. Just double-checked with my friend and learned that it was the Bloomington data. Thanks for all the effort.