# How to create a map to PNG file with specific box coordinates by Mapnik?

Tags: postgis, mapnik

I recently manually built a tile server with this instruction ->
https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-20-04-lts/.
I downloaded location data for Russia from geofabrik.de and then loaded to database by osm2pgsql.
Now all working nicely - Apache, mod_tile, renderd, Mapnik and PostgreSQL with PostGIS.

Now I want to create a program on Python for generating a PNG file with specific region (box). This region will be defined by coordinates (left and right corners of box).
I write this code:

```
import mapnik

mapnik_xml = "openstreetmap-carto/mapnik.xml"
map_output = "region_map_mapnikXml.png"

# Create a map object
m = mapnik.Map(600,300)
mapnik.load_map(m, mapnik_xml)
bbox = mapnik.Box2d(45.23, 41.34, 46.23, 43.23)
m.zoom_to_box(bbox)
mapnik.render_to_file(m, map_output)
print(f"Rendered image to {map_output}")
```

But after executing this code created only blank file with background.
I don't figure out why?
Can you help me please.

Additionaly, if I run this code:

```
import mapnik

mapnik_xml = "openstreetmap-carto/mapnik.xml"
map_output = "world_map_mapnikXml.png"

# Create a map object
m = mapnik.Map(600,300)
mapnik.load_map(m, mapnik_xml)
m.zoom_all()
mapnik.render_to_file(m, map_output)
print(f"Rendered image to {map_output}")
```

in results, generated PNG file - world map with shape of mainlands and countries.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to use a bbox with coordinates using EPSG 3857 because the OpenStreetMap Carto style use it e.g https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/blob/master/project.mml#L18

So, `bbox = mapnik.Box2d(45.23, 41.34, 46.23, 43.23)` should be instead `bbox = mapnik.Box2d(5034980.57, 5062621.68, 5146300.06, 5347045.97)`

You may want to use PyProj to calculate EPSG 3857 coordinates from longitude, latitude with

```py
from pyproj import Proj, transform

inProj = Proj('epsg:4326')
outProj = Proj('epsg:3857')

x1,y1 = -105.150271116, 39.7278572773
x2,y2 = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)
print(x2,y2)
```

PS: Proj recipe borrowed from [Converting projected coordinates to lat/lon using Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78838/converting-projected-coordinates-to-lat-lon-using-python) but doing the opposite operation (EPSG 4326 to EPSG 3857)

Comment: Thank you! I truly appreciate your help answer!

Comment: Can you tell me or where I can read about it - what this string mean?
'''
<Map background-color="#f2efe9" srs="+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0.0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +over">
'''

Comment: Go to https://epsg.io/3857 In section "Export", click Mapnik. This string is the Mapnik xml equivalent to declare your map is using background-color "#f2efe9" and srs (spatial reference system) "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0.0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +over"