# What is EPSG number for NZTM?

Tags: coordinate-system, pyproj, new-zealand

I am trying to follow the solution posted at [Converting projected coordinates to lat/lon using Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78838) to convert NZTM coordinates into WGS84.

I wrote following script to covert NZTM to WGS84:

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform

inProj = Proj(init='epsg:')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')
x1,y1 = 1400677.021,4914233.543
x2,y2 = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)
print x2,y2
```

I am not sure what would be the `epsg number` for NZTM. I tried to find it online but could not make it.

What is the EPSG number for NZTM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EPSG is 2193.

I would use a small function as follow:

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform
from pyproj import Transformer

TRAN_2193_TO_4326 = Transformer.from_crs("EPSG:2193", "EPSG:4326")

def mytransform(lat, lon):
    return TRAN_2193_TO_4326.transform(lat, lon)

latitude = mytransform(1400677.021, 4914233.543)[0]
longitude = mytransform(1400677.021, 4914233.543)[1]
```

Comment: `latitude, longitude = mytransform(1400677.021, 4914233.543)`

Answer (score 3):

EPSG is 2193

Code should be as follow:

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform

inProj = Proj(init='epsg:2193')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')
x1,y1 = 1400677.021,4914233.543
x2,y2 = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)
print x2,y2
```

**Reference:**
https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2193/

Answer (score 1):

https://epsg.io/2193, i.e. 2193

You can search on epsg.io

Comment: There is also the official EPSG registry https://epsg.org/crs_2193/NZGD2000-New-Zealand-Transverse-Mercator-2000.html?

Comment: Sure, I just find https://epsg.io a bit more modern and easy to use.

Comment: It is easier to use but it has sometimes data that is out of date. Same thing with spatialreference.org.