# Identifying coordinate system from dataset (without using GIS software)

Tags: python, coordinate-system, coordinates, folium

I've got a CSV file which I downloaded from [a Waka Kotahi open data website](https://opendata-nzta.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/crash-analysis-system-cas-data-1/explore?location=-9.665601%2C0.227812%2C2.92).

The file has got X,Y coordinates of locations.  I am using that file in Python to generate markers in Folium. I don't have ArcGIS or QGIS.

Coordinates that file contains does not look in EPSG:4326 format. I suspect that it could be NZTM coordinate system (i.e. EPSG:2193). Because value looks like (X=1406914, y= 4915023).

Is there anyway that I could find the coordinate system of coordinates without using GIS system?

Comment: 2193: https://services.arcgis.com/CXBb7LAjgIIdcsPt/arcgis/rest/services/CAS_Data_Public/FeatureServer/0

Comment: @mikewatt thanks. Last question: Do you know any website that converts coordinates into EPSG4326? I want to convert lat:-40.9006 long:174.8860 into  EPSG4326

Comment: Your coordinates look like EPSG:4326 but you seem to know that they are in some other coordinate system. What is that?

Comment: Can you download QGIS?  It would make your life easier if you're working with gis data.  Convert coords here https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4326&t_srs=3857 just change the coordinate systems to the ones you need.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78838/converting-projected-coordinates-to-lat-lon-using-python

Comment: As a rule, it's better to get the spatial reference from the data provider than trying to guess, mostly because guessing has such a high error rate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you download the shapefile instead of the CSV you'll find a .prj file in the zip which is the projection metadata:

```
PROJCS["NZGD_2000_New_Zealand_Transverse_Mercator",GEOGCS["GCS_NZGD_2000",DATUM["D_NZGD_2000",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[
"Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",1600000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northin
g",10000000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",173.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

If the next step in your processing can deal with the WKT format like this, then great!

Otherwise QGIS recognises that as `EPSG:2193 - NZGD2000 / New Zealand Transverse Mercator 2000` so you can plug that EPSG code into a conversion process.