# Creating CSV with lat/long from point shapefile using Python

Tags: python, shapefile, point, csv, latitude-longitude

Does anyone know how to create a CSV containing lat and long fields from a point shapefile in Python? I can only find info on how to make a shapefile from CSV with lat/long and not the other way around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Use [`GeoPandas`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/) to solve your problem.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
```

#### 1. Load Spatial Data

```py
gdf = gpd.read_file(shp_file_path)
```

When you load spatial data using geopandas, you can view the geometry with attribute information.
in this case the coordinates of the points.

#### 2. Make Columns from Point Geometry

```py
gdf['long'] = gdf['geometry'].x
gdf['lat'] = gdf['geometry'].y
```

#### 3. Export the Data

```py
gdf.to_csv(csv_path)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution involves the [`PyShp`](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp) package and some Python standard libraries: [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html).

Let's assume there is a point layer called *'points'* with 10 features in it, see the image below.

[image: input]

Apply the following code:

```py
# imports
import os
import csv
import shapefile

# specifying path to a shapefile
path_to_shp_file = 'P:/Test/qgis_test/points.shp'

# reading the shapefile
shp = shapefile.Reader(path_to_shp_file)

# appropriating a CSV file the name of the shapefile
csv_name = os.path.basename(shp.shapeName)
path_to_csv_file = f'P:/Test/qgis_test/{csv_name}.csv'

# making a list with fields names
fields = [field[0] for field in shp.fields[1:]] # avoiding the first deletion field 'DeletionFlag'
# adding two additional fields names for x and y coordinates
fields.extend(['x', 'y'])

# creating the CSV file
with open(path_to_csv_file, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    # writing columns
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)
    
    # writing rows
    for feat in shp.__geo_interface__['features']:
        properties = list(feat['properties'].values())
        coordinates = list(feat['geometry']['coordinates'])
        csvwriter.writerow(properties + coordinates)
```

and get the output like this:

[image: result1]

If latitude and longitude are preferred instead of projected coordinates, then try the following (includes the [`pyproj`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/) package):

```py
# imports
import os
import csv
import pyproj
import shapefile
from pyproj import CRS

# specifying path to a shapefile
path_to_shp_file = 'P:/Test/qgis_test/points.shp'

# reading the shapefile
shp = shapefile.Reader(path_to_shp_file)

# appropriating a CSV file the name of the shapefile
csv_name = os.path.basename(shp.shapeName)
path_to_csv_file = f'P:/Test/qgis_test/{csv_name}.csv'

# making a list with fields names
fields = [field[0] for field in shp.fields[1:]] # getting all fields besides the first deletion field 'DeletionFlag'
# adding two additional fields for x and y coordinates
fields.extend(['lat', 'long'])

# establishing a projection transformer
crs_from = CRS.from_user_input(25832)
crs_to = CRS.from_user_input(4326)
proj = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(crs_from, crs_to, always_xy=True)

# creating the CSV file
with open(path_to_csv_file, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    # writing columns
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)

    # writing rows
    for feat in shp.__geo_interface__['features']:
        properties = list(feat['properties'].values())
        x, y = feat['geometry']['coordinates']
        coordinates = list(proj.transform(x, y))
        csvwriter.writerow(properties + coordinates)
```

and get a bit different output:

[image: result]

---

**References:**

- [Converting projected coordinates to lat/lon using Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78838/converting-projected-coordinates-to-lat-lon-using-python)