# How to display xy coordinates (in some EPSG) using Folium

Tags: python, folium

I want to display a point/place (somewhere in Hamilton/Bermuda) with [Folium](http://python-visualization.github.io/folium/) but all I get is a blank map in Jupyter-lab:

```
import folium

map = folium.Map(location = [-64.778389, 32.289978], tiles = "OpenStreetMap", crs='EPSG4216')

map
```

[image]

Is there any explanation for that ? Did I miss something ?
Here is the link of that position in [epsg](https://epsg.io/) : https://epsg.io/map#srs=4216&x=-64.778389&y=32.289978&z=17&layer=streets

[image]

Comment: I think the projection/crs is not understood so the map fails to load. It loads fine if you pass it coordinates in EPSG4283.

Comment: Thank you. So, since Folium seems to not recognize these XY coordinates, is there a way we can transform that to Lat/Lon coordinates (in 4326 for e.g) ?

Comment: Yes. pyproj, geopandas, gdal/ogr. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/78944/2856

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS mentioned in the comment you can simply project your coordinates to 4326 before setting them in the map. Using pyproj the solution could look like:

```py
import folium
from pyproj import Transformer

t = Transformer.from_crs(4216, 4326)

x, y =  32.289978, -64.778389

map = folium.Map(location = t.transform(x, y), tiles = "OpenStreetMap")

map
```