# Reproject rasterio's bbox

Tags: python, raster, extents, rasterio

I am opening a raster with `rasterio.open()` after which I extract its `bbox`:

```
import rasterio

img = rasterio.open('myraster.tif')
bbox = img.bounds
print(bbox)

BoundingBox(left=450498.0, bottom=3509708.5, right=452789.0, top=3510922.5)
```

I want to plot it know on a `folium` map, for which I need the coordinates in lat/lon and not in UTM (which they are by default).

Is there a way to reproject the bbox directly within rasterio. My approach so  far would be to convert that bbox to a `shapely` polygon, then reproject and plot. Would there be a more direct solution to avoid creating the `shapely` polygon?

Comment: `The simplest way to transform coordinates in Python is pyproj:` https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/78944/35561

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pyproj`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/index.html).  Specifically the [pyproj.transformer.Transformer](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/transformer.html#pyproj.transformer.Transformer) class.

```
import rasterio as rio
from pyproj import Transformer

with rio.open('myraster.tif') as img:
    xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = img.bounds
    transformer = Transformer.from_crs(img.crs, "EPSG:4326")

    ul = transformer.transform(xmin,ymax)
    lr = transformer.transform(xmax,ymin)

    print(ul, lr)
```

Comment: Thanks, was working on this direction :)